# javascript: how to use generators as class methods

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

My class looks like this:

```
class Test {
  constructor() {

  }

  *test() {
    console.log('test');
    let result = yield this.something();
    return result;
  }

  something() {
    console.log('something');
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      resolve(2);
    });
  }
}
```

But when I create an object from `Test` and call the `test()` method, I don't get the expected result ...

```
let test = new Test();
console.log(test.test()); // {}
```

Thought it would return `2`.

Logs aren't shown as well.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: Try `console.log(Array.from(test.test()))`.

Comment: @Cerbrus 2 - added that to the question

Comment: Have a look at [MDN - Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Generator) to refresh your memory about generators.

Comment: @FelixKling was using coroutines for too long - expected their behavior to be the default generator behavior ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works properly. You need to call next() on returned value by test method.

```
let test = new Test();
console.log(test.test().next());
```

Output

```
test
something
{ value: Promise { 2 }, done: false }
```

By calling test.test() you are creating new generator instance. Then you should call next() function on created instance to make generator yield value.